# error saying:- Idling, State changed from up to starting, Stopping all processes with SIGTERM, Process exited with status 143

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, heroku, server

I am trying to register and it seems like my database is not connected to my back-end

this is the following code I have written in my server file:-

```
import express from 'express';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt-nodejs';
import cors from 'cors';
import knex from 'knex'; 

import register from './controllers/register.js';
import signin from './controllers/signin.js';
import profile from './controllers/profile.js';
import image from './controllers/image.js';

const db = knex({
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
        connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
        ssl: true,
    }
});


const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

app.get('/', (req, res)=> { res.send(`it is workinggggg broooo!`)})

app.post('/signin', (req, res) => { signin(req, res, db, bcrypt) })

app.post('/register', (req, res) => { register(req, res, db, bcrypt) })

app.get('/profile/:id', (req, res) => { profile(req, res, db) })

app.put('/image', (req, res) => { image.handleImage(req, res, db)})

app.post('/imageurl', (req, res) => { image.handleApiCall(req, res)})
  
app.listen( process.env.PORT || 3000 , ()=> {
    console.log(`app is running on port  ${process.env.PORT}`);
});
```

After running "heroku logs --tail" in my server I get these following errors:

```
"

2020-06-20T21:57:19.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded

2020-06-20T21:57:20.041241+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting

2020-06-20T21:57:20.057729+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting

2020-06-20T21:57:21.325688+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM

2020-06-20T21:57:21.423767+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143

2020-06-20T21:57:22.448784+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`

2020-06-20T21:57:24.710984+00:00 app[web.1]:

2020-06-20T21:57:24.711011+00:00 app[web.1]: > backend@1.0.0 start /app

2020-06-20T21:57:24.711012+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js

2020-06-20T21:57:24.711012+00:00 app[web.1]:

2020-06-20T21:57:25.233826+00:00 app[web.1]: App is running on port 18490

2020-06-20T21:57:25.558723+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up

2020-06-20T22:01:56.641042+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=OPTIONS path="/register" host=ztmsmartbrainapi.herokuapp.com request_id=a113ac16-2729-461a-bc55-fe4780bd1a06 fwd="170.80.70.144" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7ms status=204 bytes=301 protocol=https

2020-06-20T22:01:57.069295+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/register" host=ztmsmartbrainapi.herokuapp.com request_id=64d15e45-8478-4809-b433-fb2a73f66c55 fwd="170.80.70.144" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=292ms status=400 bytes=268 protocol=https

2020-06-20T22:02:58.588010+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=ztmsmartbrainapi.herokuapp.com request_id=e1a0e6b8-56d6-43b3-bb68-3aa512630094 fwd="170.80.70.144" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=181 protocol=https

2020-06-20T22:07:23.105112+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=ztmsmartbrainapi.herokuapp.com request_id=31e8f076-ba82-4854-8b64-45246ba5852b fwd="170.80.70.144" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=181 protocol=https

2020-06-20T22:07:46.020501+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=OPTIONS path="/register" host=ztmsmartbrainapi.herokuapp.com request_id=4253b32c-7c34-4529-92f7-047a0be69304 fwd="170.80.70.144" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=204 bytes=301 protocol=https

2020-06-20T22:07:46.612772+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/register" host=ztmsmartbrainapi.herokuapp.com request_id=dbc96cea-62f7-4e2f-9515-dc0addf3a9ac fwd="170.80.70.144" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=447ms status=400 bytes=268 protocol=https
```

the error it showed in the network was

```
{"code":"DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT"}
```

this error had been eating me up for days and I wasn't able to find any accurate solutions to it, that's y decided to post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well idk the reason for the following error well i would surely like to know that from someone in the comments.

though the solution for this problem was to change this from the server js file

```
const db = knex({
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
        connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
        ssl: true,
    }
});
```

to this

```
const db = knex({
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
        connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
        ssl: {

            rejectUnauthorized: false
        
          }
    }
});
```